# How to make it so that I can server deafen a mentioned user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I tried everything at it would give me errors such as
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setDeaf' of undefined
Please and thank you.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const config = require('../config.json')
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args, config) => {
    
    if(message.author.id !== "247227873734295562") return message.channel.send("no perms")
    const mUser = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]);
    let isDeafened = false; 
   if(!mUser) {
       message.channel.send("You need to mention a user!")
   }
   if(mUser) {
       mUser.voice.setDeaf(true)
   } 
    
}
module.exports.help = {
    name: "d",
    description: "Server deafens a mentioned user forever",
    usage: `${config.prefix}d <@mention>`,
    ex: `${config.prefix}d <@247227873734295562>`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code and you getting that error seems to show, that `mUser` doesn't have the property `voice`.
Which Discord.js version do you use?

`mUser.voice.setDeaf(true)` was added in [v12](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html). So, if you have an earlier version, you should use `mUser.setDeaf(true)` instead.